# css alignment not working on mobile

Tags: html, css, centering

I have this code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!--Website made by William Stinson, 2016, Unsolicitedly.-->
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .center {
      text-align: center;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="center">
    <a href="http://www.gifford.org">
      <img src="http://www.myhopesanddreams.com/william/giffordlogo.png" draggable="false" alt="logo" />
    </a>
    <br>
    <img src="myhopesanddreams.com/Untitled 3.png" height="100" draggable="false">
    <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/gifford.org/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAojv3USFoCWLpHJeIoSEiOydke0dKV3wmS-EWrr4-qbxryw/viewform?embedded=true" width="1300" height="1000" frameborder="3" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
    <h1>Created for The Gifford School by William Stinson</h1>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

It centers properly on desktop devices, but on mobile devices, it is not centering properly. How can I fix this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your `<iframe>` has `width="1300"` - how do you expect that to even fit on a mobile screen?

Comment: @connexo mobile as in retina ipads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your `iframe` width

```css
.center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="center">
  <a href="http://www.gifford.org">
    <img src="http://www.myhopesanddreams.com/william/giffordlogo.png" draggable="false" alt="logo" />
  </a>
  <br><img src="myhopesanddreams.com/Untitled 3.png" height="100" draggable="false">
  <iframe src="https://docs.google.com/a/gifford.org/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeAojv3USFoCWLpHJeIoSEiOydke0dKV3wmS-EWrr4-qbxryw/viewform?embedded=true" width="98%" height="1000px" frameborder="3" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0">Loading...</iframe>
  <h1>Created for The Gifford School by William Stinson</h1>
</div>
```

Here is a [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/mp8xyoq3/2/)